# Posting data to a RESTful-webservice - Why does this code work in eclipse, but not on android?

Tags: android, asp.net, rest, http-post, restful-url

I've been trying call an asp.net RESTful API - Webservice from an Android Device but it dosen't work yet. When I run my code it throws an exception, but exception.getMessage() dosen't return anything.
I only know that it can be neither an IO-, nor a MalformedURLException, 
since I've tested the code with catches for both respectively instead of one catch for exceptions in general which lead the app to crash.
The Webserver works fine, also I succeeded calling it from a regular Java-Client in Eclipse. I can also access it from my device, thus I'd conclude that there has to be some missing android-permission rather than a problem with the server or the java-code.

EDIT: I think that the exception is thrown by "OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream()"

```
public void postRequest(View view) {
      try {
          URL url = new URL("http://IP:PORT/api/get");
          HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
          conn.setDoOutput(true);
          conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
          conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
          String input = "{\"parameter1\":\"abc\",\"parameter2\":\"def\"}";

          OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
          os.write(input.getBytes());
          os.flush();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="PPEASE Fotos"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".FullscreenActivity">
        <!-- The meta-data tag is required if you support API level 15 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".FullscreenActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Sources:
https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restfull-java-client-with-java-net-url/
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: Okay, sorry for that

Comment: Try adding a conn.connect() after the flush

Comment: Adding this command after os.flush() dosen't change anything. Do you have any other advise or did I just place it wrong?